# Cursor and SUBSTR usage in procedure

Tags: plsql, cursor, substr

I need to trim instance name from complete dblink name .For example The select query returns result like HHVISDEV.TRINITI.COM. I need to get HHVISDEV. And ofcourse There are such multiple results. So I need to use cursor and print the final result. I am getting `Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.`, when I compile.  And when I call the procedure I am getting ERROR at line 1:
    `ORA-06575: Package or function DELETEDBLINKS1 is in an invalid state.` Can any one please guide me.

```
create or replace procedure DeleteDBLinks1 is
  cursor mycursor is
    SELECT SUBSTR(DB_LINK, 1, INSTR(DB_LINK, '.', 1, 1) - 1)
      FROM dba_db_links;
  myvar dba_db_links.dblinks%TYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN mycursor;

  LOOP
    FETCH mycursor
      INTO myvar;

    EXIT WHEN mycursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(myvar);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE mycursor;
end;
/
```

Comment: What is the compilation error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you see `Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors`, then, I can guess, you compile your procedure in SQL*Plus. In SQL*Plus you can run command

```
show errors
```

and you will see errors list. Your procedure looks OK, so I think problem is - you have no access to `dba_db_links` view. Try to use `all_db_links` or `user_db_links` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Along with what Dmitry said about you probably not having access to dba_db_links table, you also had a typo in the myvar variable definition.  It should have been:

```
    myvar dba_db_links.db_link%TYPE;
```

SQL*Plus> SHOW ERRORS will help you in your PL/SQL endeavors, until you start using a PL/SQL IDE like SQL Developer or (my favorite) PL/SQL Developer, which will show you the errors automatically.